# Javascript: bitwise in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs

I apologize if this is stupid question. I use [vue-moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-moment) in a Vuejs application and have the following code:

```
<!-- date = '2020-03-23 01:01:01' -->
<span>{{ date | moment('from', 'now')  }}</span>
```

The value within span is returned to `xyz minutes ago`, which is correct. My question is how does bitwise operator works here? Is it bitwise or something else? how does vue-moment retrieves the value of date and parses it? I don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This operator is called `pipe` and what you see here is an example of [Vue filters](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html). The value on the left passed through the pipe to functions on the right, the final value is then displayed. It is often used to format value in a desired way.

Comment: Thanks! Never heard of them. Is it possible to escape general bitwise `|` within vue's moustache syntax?

Comment: Um, I've never seen usage of bitwise in a moustache syntax... Even if you can't escape it, you can always use `computed` and do bitwise operations there.